# Accordion baseado numa table com icones

Tags: html, jquery, table, accordion

Estou construindo um accordion baseado numa table para mostrar registros com o seguinte código:

```
<style>
table{ width: 75%; }
tr {border: 2px solid #AEAEAE;}
.border1 {border:  1px solid #ddd; padding:3px; }
.imgmais {  width: 20px; height: 20px; background: url(ic_mais.png) center center/20px no-repeat; ;}
.imgmenos {  width: 20px; height: 20px; background: url(ic_menos.png) center center/20px no-repeat; ;}
.topico { width: 100%; display:inline-block; height: 30px; border:1px solid red;}
.topico-item { float:left;  border:0px solid black;}
.tam1 {width: 40px;}

</style>

<table id="table_a">
    <tr><td class="tam1"><input class="radio" type="radio" name="rdbsel" value="777777" id="rad001"/></div></td><td>Fazenda São Carlos</td><td><div id="icone-001" class="imgmais"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><div class="border1"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p></div>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td class="tam1"><input class="radio" type="radio" name="rdbsel" value="666666" id="rad002"/></div></td><td>Frigorífico Avícola Votuporanga Ltda (Núcleo I e II)</td><td><div id="icone-002" class="imgmais"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><div class="border1"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p></div>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td class="tam1"><input class="radio" type="radio" name="rdbsel" value="333333" id="rad003"/></div></td><td>Estancia Frango Rico</td><td><div id="icone-003" class="imgmais"></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><div class="border1"><p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</p></div>
    </td></tr>
</table>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'>
<script>

$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=3]").find("p").hide();

    $("#table_a").find('.radio').click(function(event) {
        let _idrbt = $(this).attr('id');
        $("table").find(".imgmenos").closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
        $("table").find(".imgmenos").removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
    });

    $("#table_a").find('.imgmais').click(function(event) {

            let _idrowclicada = $(this).attr('class');
            $("table").find(".imgmenos").closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
            $("table").find(".imgmenos").removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
            if( _idrowclicada=='imgmais' ){  
                $(this).removeClass('imgmais').addClass('imgmenos');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
            }

            let $target = $(event.target);
            $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
    });
});

<script>
```

O controle é realizado pelo JQuery. Cada linha possui um ícone (+) que expande o detalhe ou (-) que esconde o detalhe. Expando o detalhe de uma linha, e quando expando outra linha ele esconde o detalhe anterior. O problema acontece quando só tenho um detalhe expandido e tento fechar ele mesmo, ai ele se perde, esconde e expande em seguida. Depois muda o ícone. Poderiam me ajudar a verificar aonde está o erro nessa situação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está no trecho de expandir e recolher o parágrafo:

```
$("#table_a").find('.imgmais').click(function(event) {
    let _idrowclicada = $(this).attr('class');

    $("table").find(".imgmenos").closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
    $("table").find(".imgmenos").removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');

    if( _idrowclicada=='imgmais' ){  
        $(this).removeClass('imgmais').addClass('imgmenos');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
    }

    let $target = $(event.target);
    $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
});
```

Perceba que independente do estado do item clicado, você sempre tenta recolher o parágrafo e trocar a imagem:

```
$("table").find(".imgmenos").closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
$("table").find(".imgmenos").removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
```

Porém esse trecho só deve ocorrer, caso o item clicado ainda não esteja expandido, ou seja, quando foi clicado no *mais*, como você já tem uma condição que verifica isso:

```
if( _idrowclicada=='imgmais' ){
```

Basta então colocar o trecho dentro dessa condição:

```
if( _idrowclicada=='imgmais' ){  
    $("table").find(".imgmenos").closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
    $("table").find(".imgmenos").removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
    $(this).removeClass('imgmais').addClass('imgmenos');
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
}
```

---

Seu código completo então ficará mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```js
$(function() {
    $("td[colspan=3]").find("p").hide();

    $("#table_a").find('.radio').click(function(event) {
        let _idrbt = $(this).attr('id');
        $("table").find(".imgmenos").closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
        $("table").find(".imgmenos").removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
    });

    $("#table_a").find('.imgmais').click(function(event) {
        let _idrowclicada = $(this).attr('class');

        if( _idrowclicada=='imgmais' ){  
            $("table").find(".imgmenos").closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
            $("table").find(".imgmenos").removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
            $(this).removeClass('imgmais').addClass('imgmenos');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('imgmenos').addClass('imgmais');
        }

        let $target = $(event.target);
        $target.closest("tr").next().find("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 75%;
}

tr {
    border: 2px solid #AEAEAE;
}

.border1 {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 3px;
}

.imgmais {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gAlw.png) center center/20px no-repeat;
}

.imgmenos {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LHtV.png) center center/20px no-repeat;
}

.topico {
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.topico-item {
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid black;
}

.tam1 {
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<table id="table_a">
    <tr>
        <td class="tam1">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" name="rdbsel" value="777777" id="rad001"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          Fazenda São Carlos
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="icone-001" class="imgmais">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class="border1">
                <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="tam1">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" name="rdbsel" value="666666" id="rad002"/>
        </td>
        <td>Frigorífico Avícola Votuporanga Ltda (Núcleo I e II)</td>
        <td>
            <div id="icone-002" class="imgmais"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class="border1">
                <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="tam1">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" name="rdbsel" value="333333" id="rad003"/>
        </td>
        <td>Estancia Frango Rico</td>
        <td>
            <div id="icone-003" class="imgmais"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class="border1">
                <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
                </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfeitíssimo. Agradeço mais uma vez o auxilio.